# Is a point contained in one of the curves during a transformation?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Suppose I have two curves $c_1$ and $c_2$:

$$c_1: I\rightarrow \Bbb R^2$$
$$c_2: I\rightarrow \Bbb R^2$$

Where $I = [-1,1] \subset \Bbb R $.

I've drawn a crude image here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1i7QpXInfhHbm7aHFlyHRkik0YMSIYlQ_

$c_1(0)=c_2(0) = (0,0) = O$

$P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$ are points in the gaps between the two curves.

Suppose $|OP_1|=|OP_2|=|OP_3|=|OP_4|=d$

Suppose I know there is a continuous transformation turning $c_1$ into $c_2$. I also know that this continuous transformation maintains $c_1(0) = 0$ during the transformation.

I want to know under what conditions one of the in-between curves during this transformation contains at least one of $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$.

I know that we could shrink $c_1$ to the origin, then stretch it out to $c_2$ avoiding all the points. So a necessary condition would be that there exists a point at a distance d from O on the curve during the transformation. What other conditions are necessary?

Are there any theorems related to this? Thanks.

Comment: $I \subset \Bbb R = [-1,1]$ doesn't sound right, is it  a typo? Do you mean  $I= [-1,1]\subset \Bbb R$ ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H:I\times I\to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^0$ homotopy (which is precisely the deformation you were talking about) such that $H(0,t)=c_1(t)$, $H(1,t)=c_2(t)$ and $H(0,s)=0$ for all $t$ and $s$ in $I$. Your condition is something like:

There exists $\tau\in I$ (which by a reparametrisation one can assume equal to $\frac{1}{2}$) such that for every $s$, $H(s,\tau)$ is at distance $d$ from the origin. The result follows by the fact that continuous maps sends connected sets to connected sets.

Comment: So $H(s,\tau)$ maps out a circle arc of radius d and so it intersects one of those points. Is that right?

Comment: I mean $H(s,0.5)$ maps out a circle arc of radius d and so it intersects one of those points.

Comment: that's the idea. Call for instance $A=\{H(s,\tau):s\in I\}\subset S^2$. This set must be connected, and since it contains an intersection of the curve $c_1$ and $c_2$ with the circle, it has to pass through some $P$. Be careful: the point $H(s,\tau)$ must change continuously (i.e. one cannot jump from a point at distance $d$ on the right of $c_1$ for instance to a new one at distance $d$ on the left. In that case is easy to imagine a counterexample, since $A$ is not connected anymore.)

Comment: Once again, the connectedness of $A$ is given by the fact that the map $s\mapsto H(s,\tau)$ is continuous, and continuous maps send connected sets ($I$) to connected sets (in this case $A$).

Comment: So, I've edited a bit my answer to provide it.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your help.